# How can I change the class name when I convert using pyside2-uic command?

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to create GUI program by pyside2.

I use the command below to convert the .ui file to .py file.

**"pyside2-uic mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.py" -- conversion command**

After converting, The default class name is "Ui_MainWindow".

**Can I set the name of the class I want when I enter above the command?**

**Now, after conversion, I change the class name in .py**

Below is the result when I enter "pyside2-uic -help" command.

```
Options:
  -?, -h, --help                Displays help on commandline options.
  --help-all                    Displays help including Qt specific options.
  -v, --version                 Displays version information.
  -d, --dependencies            Display the dependencies.
  -o, --output <file>           Place the output into <file>
  -a, --no-autoconnection       Do not generate a call to
                                QObject::connectSlotsByName().
  -p, --no-protection           Disable header protection.
  -n, --no-implicit-includes    Disable generation of #include-directives.
  -s, --no-stringliteral        Deprecated. The use of this option won't take
                                any effect.
  --postfix <postfix>           Postfix to add to all generated classnames.
  --tr, --translate <function>  Use <function> for i18n.
  --include <include-file>      Add #include <include-file> to <file>.
  -g, --generator <python|cpp>  Select generator.
  --idbased                     Use id based function for i18n
  --from-imports                Python: generate imports relative to '.'
```

I couldn't find the command I want.

======================================================

**This question was resolved by the method of comment.**

Comment: No, you can't from that command. But that would be quite pointless, why do you want to do that?

Comment: @musicamante

Well.. I thought about the case when there are several ui files and I try to convert them at once. At this time, I think it is quite cumbersome to open each py file and modify the class name.

Comment: You should change the object name of the top level widget in Designer instead.

Comment: I have not modified the object name in QT designer. I'll try it.

Comment: @musicamante  Thank you, I resolved it using the method you told me.